# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty - Even when SECRET_KEY is set in settings.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm having this error while trying to run my Teonite_project/web_scrapper.py script:

```
File "C:/Users/kfhei/Desktop/Teonite_project/Teonite_project/web_scrapper.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\Teonite_project\Teonite_project\settings.py", line 15, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\kfhei\Desktop\Teonite_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 125, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

My script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
#import simplejson as json

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Teonite_project.settings")
import django
django.setup()

from words.models import Word
from authors.models import Author

URL_DOMAIN = 'https://teonite.com/blog/'

def get_links(url):
    '''
    Returning the array of links
    to blog articles from the website
    '''

    html = get_html(url)
    links = []

    for link in html.findAll('a'):
        link =  link.get('href')
        if link == None or link[6:9] == 'tag' or link[6:10]=='page':
            pass
        elif link[:6] == '/blog/':
            link = url[:19] + link
            links.append(link)

    return links

def get_html(url):
    '''
        Returning the HTML of the website
    '''

    req = Request(url)
    html_page = urlopen(req)
    html = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
    return html

def get_text(url):
    '''
        Extracting the post content of
        the articles from the blog
    '''

    html = get_html(url)
    text =''
    for content in html.select('.post-content'):
        text = text + content.text
    return content.text

def get_author(url):
    '''
        Extracting the name of the Author
        from the articles
    '''
    html = get_html(url)
    for author in html.select('.author-content'):
        return author.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
        Main function tasks:
        * Extract the neccessary data from the website,
        * Save it to the database
    '''
    links = get_links(URL_DOMAIN)
    author_dict_database = {}
    word_dict_database = {}

    for link in links:
        text = get_text(link).strip()
        wordslist = text.split()
        author = get_author(link).strip()

        for word in wordslist:
            if not word.isalpha():
                wordslist.remove(word)
            word = word.lower()

        if author in author_dict_database:
            for word in wordslist:
                if word in word_dict_database:
                    author_dict_database[author][word] += 1
                else:
                    author_dict_database[author][word] = 1
        else:
            for word in wordslist:
                if word in word_dict_database:
                    word_dict_database[word] += 1
                else:
                    word_dict_database[word] = 1
            author_dict_database[author] = word_dict_database

    #Saving values to postgres database

    for key_author,word_dict in author_dict_database:
        database_author = Author(author=key_author)
        for key_word, value_count in word_dict:
            database_word = Word(author=key_author, words_list=key_word, words_count=value_count)
```

As you can seen I tried different things to make it work. I've read several topics in stackoverflow and tried to search in different websites.
Also I have configured the wsgi.py file

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Teonite_project.settings")
```

Unfortunately I have no idea why this happens, because I have set the SECRET_KEY in my Teonite_project/Teonite_project/settings.py

Basically all I want is to run my script, and add the scrapped values to my postgres database in my authors, and words models.

Comment: Can you show your directory layout - where is the settings file in relation to this script? Also, please show exactly how you are invoking this script.

Comment: I think you are calling `django.setup()` from the same file that is supposed to be your settings file (according to the error trace). I don't think that's supported. Basically `django.setup()` is being called twice: from `Teonite_project\settings.py` and from  `Teonite_project/web_scrapper.py`

Comment: @JoseKilo Thanks! It helped a lot! I forgot I put the same line of code in the setting.py file...
Right now I'm having other error, but this one is easy :D